# *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe B

Tags: drivers, intel

I planned to use my old copmpaq 6710b for some pythonic work. I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it but noticed it ran extremely slow. So I switched to Xubuntu, but again, the gui is horribly slow and unresponsive. So I took a look at `dmesg` and noticed some errors. Googling this gave me a hint about an old bug but I couldn't find anything about how to fix it?

```
[  910.152505] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x82000008.
[  910.152734] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 15.32.2.9
[  910.170267] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[  910.170396] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: Status: 0x000202E4, count: 1
[  910.170494] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: Desc       Time       asrtPC  blink2 ilink1  nmiPC   Line
[  910.191536] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: SYSASSERT     (0x5) 3085923610 0x008B6 0x1118E 0x00320 0x00000 659

[  910.191577] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: Error Reply type 0x00000000 cmd C_TX  (0x1C) seq 0x00FB ser 0x00000000 
[  910.321536] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: Can't stop Rx DMA. 
[  910.575203] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested 
[  928.677041] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe B (start=54760 end=54761) time 16908 us, min 795, max 799, scanline start 363, end 387 
[ 1029.867391] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x82000008. 
[ 1029.867405] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 15.32.2.9 
[ 1029.867444] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump: 
[ 1029.867451] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: Status: 0x000202E5, count: 1 
[ 1029.867457] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: Desc       Time       asrtPC  blink2 ilink1  nmiPC   Line 
[ 1029.867693] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: SYSASSERT     (0x5) 3205641493 0x008B6 0x1118E 0x00320 0x00000 659
[ 1029.867726] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: Error Reply type 0x00000000 cmd C_TX (0x1C) seq 0x001A ser 0x00000000 
[ 1030.484244] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: Error sending C_RXON: time out after 500ms. 
[ 1030.484255] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: Error clearing ASSOC_MSK on current configuration (-110). 
[ 1030.487932] iwl3945 0000:10:00.0: Can't stop Rx DMA. 
[ 1030.491315] ieee80211 phy0: Hardware restart was requested 
[ 1353.471573] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe B (start=80297 end=80298) time 96 us, min 795, max 799, scanline start 788, end 801 
[ 1370.703647] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe B (start=81334 end=81335) time 95 us, min 795, max 799, scanline start 787, end 800 
[ 1399.176247] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]]
*ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe B (start=83047 end=83048) time 95 us, min 795, max 799, scanline start 790, end 801 
[ 1408.087869] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe B (start=83583 end=83584) time 97 us, min 795, max 799, scanline start 788, end 799 
[ 1436.436458] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]]
*ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe B (start=85288 end=85289) time 96 us, min 795, max 799, scanline start 787, end 800 
[ 1450.520541] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe B (start=86135 end=86136) time 95 us, min 795, max 799, scanline start 788, end 801 
[ 1453.031679] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]]
*ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe B (start=86286 end=86287) time 96 us, min 795, max 799, scanline start 788, end 801 
[ 1465.004819] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe B (start=87006 end=87007) time 95 us, min 795, max 799, scanline start 788, end 800 
[ 3732.207332] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]]
*ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe B (start=49438 end=49439) time 96 us, min 795, max 799, scanline start 789, end 800 
[ 3736.116095] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]] *ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe B (start=49673 end=49674) time 95 us, min 795, max 799, scanline start 792, end 800 
[ 3769.831846] [drm:intel_pipe_update_end [i915]]
*ERROR* Atomic update failure on pipe B (start=51700 end=51701) time 96 us, min 795, max 799, scanline start 787, end 799
```

Comment: It seems like you have a problem similar to mine, please add details of your setup to this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1660619